# How to input single-letter author names?

Tags: bibtex

Consider the following

```
@misc{Person19,
 author = "A Person",
 title = "An Article",
 year = "2019"
}

@misc{Person19',
 author = "Another Person",
 title = "Another Article",
 year = "2019"
}
```

in combination with

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{cite}
\begin{document}

\nocite{Person19,Person19'}

\bibliographystyle{abbrv}
\bibliography{paper}
\end{document}
```

This is rendered as (using `latexmk -pdf`)

> References
>
> [1] A. Person. Another article, 2019.
>
> [2] A. Person. An article, 2019.

Here "A" is the full name in the second reference -- but a dot is still added after the full name! My question is how I can input the author's name such that the dot is not added in the output.

Comment: `abbrv` abbreviates names. And the abbreviation of the first name 'A' is 'A.' according to BibTeX (not entirely unreasonably). If you want full names, use a style that does not abbreviate names (`plain` for example). Then of course 'Anne' will also remain 'Anne' and will not become 'A.'.

Comment: Thanks, but I think abbreviating "A" as "A." is entirely unreasonable, and would therefore like the output to be just "A".

Comment: Well, I guess there a points to be made for both sides. What about other names? Should "Anne" still become "A." or would "Anne" be fine?

Comment: "Anne" should be rendered as "A.". To clarify: Names must be abbreviated, but no dots should be added after single-letter names.

Comment: @moewe -- Under some circumstances, when single-letter names are given by parents, some government documents are "adjusted" to indicate this by adding "only" to the letter.  One example of a person with single-letter given names is the mathematician [R H Bing](http://www.genealogy.ams.org/id.php?id=305); he was referred to by one of my coworkers at AMS as "Ronly Honly Bing".  (This really should have been accommodated properly by BibTeX.)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is an ugly workaround that seems to work for the case here. It removes a `.` following the name initial. If the BibTeX style does some weird stuff to the name field this may break down.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{cite}

\makeatletter
\newcommand*{\dotgobble}{%
  \aftergroup\dotgobble@i}

\newcommand*{\dotgobble@i}{%
  \@ifnextchar.
    {\@gobble}
    {}}
\makeatother

\usepackage{filecontents}
\begin{filecontents}{\jobname.bib}
@misc{Person18,
 author = {{\relax A\dotgobble} Person},
 title  = {An Article},
 year   = {2019},
}
@misc{Person19,
 author = {Another Person},
 title  = {Another Article},
 year   = {2019},
}
\end{filecontents}

\begin{document}
\nocite{Person18,Person19}

\bibliographystyle{abbrv}
\bibliography{\jobname}
\end{document}
```

[image: [1] A. Person. Another article, 2019.//[2] A Person. An article, 2019.]

I guess it would be nicer to modify the `.bst` file to avoid placing the dot in the first place, but I don't have the time for that at the moment.